# Error in R: unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbWriteTable’

Tags: r, computer-science

I'm trying to write a table in a db using R and I got this error:

Script:

```
try(
silent = TRUE, {
dbWriteTable(conn, tableName, csvData, append = app, overwrite = !app)
dbDisconnect(conn)})
```

PS.: `app <- FALSE`

Error:

> "Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : \n  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbWriteTable’ for signature ‘\"character\", \"character\", \"data.frame\"’\n"
>   attr(,"class")
>   [1] "try-error"
>   attr(,"condition")
>   \001NULL\001, skeleton = (function (conn,     name, value, ...) stop("invalid call in method dispatch to 'dbWriteTable' (no ...

Comment: Please edit to make note of where functions come from.

Comment: That function typically takes an object as the first in its signature, not `character`. For example [`RPostgres::dbWriteTable`](https://github.com/r-dbi/RPostgres/blob/master/R/tables.R#L51) has a signature of `c("PqConnection", "character", "data.frame")`. This suggests that your `conn` is not what it should be.

Comment: Thank you! I need to set a connection object instead of a 'character'

Comment: @MatheusSilva could you put that solution in an answer?

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me because the object I was providing was not a data.frame (or tibble).

```
dbWriteTable(conn, tableName, csvData, append = app, overwrite = !app)
```

How I fixed it was to simply convert the object to a data.frame before calling `dbWriteTable()`

```
csvData <- as.data.frame(csvData)
dbWriteTable(conn, tableName, csvData, append = app, overwrite = !app)
#  It works!
```